# Android Studio Command Line SDK is not showing in the SDK Manager

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, android-studio-2.3

I'm new to Flutter and I installed successfully Android Studio v2.3.1 and in the SDK Manager, I wanted to turn on the checkbox of **Android SDK Command Line Tools** but it does not there!

Here is the screenshot of my Android Studio Sdk Manager:

[image: sdk-tools-image]

So what's going wrong here, how can I install this sdk properly in the Android Studio?

Please help me out to get started with Flutter, I'm really stuck with this prob.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That looks like a very very old Android SDK installation. HAXM is now marked deprecated and the "Android Support repository" and "Google Repository" are long removed from Android SDK. Based on the Platform-Tools my guess this installation is about 7 years old. My recommendation is to delete it and start with a fresh Android SDK installation.